# HttpWebRequest not receiving response at all

Tags: c#, timeout, httpclient, httpwebrequest

I want to retrieve a string from the API.
I have the following code:

```
public string Get()
{      
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

    request.Timeout= timeOut;
    request.ReadWriteTimeout = timeOut;

    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        return reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

timeout is set to 20 min (20*60000ms).

when api is processing about 5 minutes then everything works perfectly. I get the result.

The problem is when api processes data longer, about 12 min.
When I call API from chrome browser, after 12 min I get the result correctly.
But when I try to call the same api from the c# program, I don't get any result. The program ends with timeout (in my case 20 min) despite I know that api processes data for about 12 min

what am i doing wrong?

btw. I have the same problem when I use `HttpClient` instead of `HttpWebResponse`

**Edit:
I was able to solve the problem by setting the ContinueTimeout property to timeOut.**

```
request.ContinueTimeout = timeOut;
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.continuetimeout?view=net-5.0

Now everything works

Comment: Still TimeoutException? Where exactly do you get it? Could you provide a StackTrace?

Comment: at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

"Message: The operation has timed out"

but as I previously explained, this is client timeOut (after 20min) 
server should finish processing in 12 min and when I run it from browser, entering URL, it generates result in 12 min.

I don't have access to server implementation

Comment: So GetResponse times out and not the read part from the result stream. In this case, the ReadWriteTimeout indeed doesn't matter.

Comment: @rozx Welcome to StackOverflow. 12 minutes response time seems to me a lot. Can't you change the communication flow in the way, that you can issue a request and get immediate response that the job has been received? Then either you can poll the job or get notified by the downstream system to get knowledge about completion or failure.

Comment: This would probably be a better solution. Unfortunately I do not have the possibility to change it.

Comment: @rozx In case of HttpClient, please try to create a per request `CancellationTokenSource` and pass its `Token` to your request: `using var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(timeOut); await httpClient.GetAsync(url, tokenSource.Token);` Did it help?